# enum flagsattribute

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to evaluate an enum with the FlagsAttribute applied as shown below. The problem is the ridiculous amount of code its taking to ensure the proper *if* statement runs. I've got four *if* statements that should only execute if specific combinations of the enum are set but **nothing else**:

1. Private, Static
2. Private
3. Privileged
4. Public

Detecting the existence of the required flags is easy but I also have to ensure that **no** other flags are set which is a ridiculous amount of code to type and looks like a maintenance nightmare.

```
[Flags]
public enum AccessModifierType : short
{
    Infer = 1,
    Public = 2,
    Privileged = 4,
    Private = 8,
    Static = 16
}
```

**Can anyone re-write this *if* statement to be more concise?**

```
if ((Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType & AccessModifierType.Public) == AccessModifierType.Public
        && (Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType & AccessModifierType.Static) != AccessModifierType.Static
        && (Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType & AccessModifierType.Privileged) != AccessModifierType.Privileged
        && (Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType & AccessModifierType.Private) != AccessModifierType.Private){
}
```

Comment: Well you can at least replace the == X and != X with != 0 and == 0 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how your final sample relates to your original requirements (I get the feeling that `Infer` has some special meaning?) but if you're looking for a *specific* bit combination and nothing else, why not just use an equality test against the exact expected enum value (assembled through bitwise ORs)?

```
if(myUnknownFlagsEnumValue == (MyEnum.RequiredFlag1 | MyEnum.RequiredFlag2))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Some good answers here. I’m going with Ani’s answer because that is what I was originally using but was getting the wrong results due to yet another enum issue earlier in the code and I wandered off the road.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, comparing to 0 is easier, as is hoisting a value you are using repeatedly:

```
var access = Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType;
if ((access & AccessModifierType.Public) != 0
    && (access & AccessModifierType.Static) == 0
    && (access & AccessModifierType.Privileged) == 0
    && (access & AccessModifierType.Private) == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to test **and no other flag**, then just:

```
if (Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType == AccessModifierType.Public)
{
    ...
}
```

If you want it to be public but not any of the other three? Then presumably:

```
if(Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType & (
     AccessModifierType.Public | AccessModifierType.Static |
     AccessModifierType.Priveleged | AccessModifierType.Private
    ) ==  AccessModifierType.Public)
{
   ...
}
```

This has the advantage of only being one test (I would also expect the compiler to perform the `|` during build, so this is just "`ldc`, `and`, `brtrue`" or "`ldc`, `and`, `brfalse`"

Answer (score 0):

Surely to test if only one flag is set you just test against that flag:

```
if( Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType == AccessModifierType.Private)
...
```

To see if it equals an exact combination of flags, again, test against that combination:

```
if( Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType == (AccessModifierType.Private & AccessModifierType.Static))
...
```

To get your head around this remember that an enum is actually just a number. So if your enum has a value of Private it is just stored as 8, so just test if it equal to 8 (or Private). If it is Private and Static then it is 8 + 16 = 24. So to test if it is both of those then just test if it eqaul to 24 (or Private & Static).

Answer (score 0):

If you use some extensions methods - examples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37921/Enums-Flags-and-C-Oh-my-bad-pun) then you should be able to simplify your code.

```
AccessModifierType modifier = Model.CurrentContext.CurrentAccessModifierType;
if (modifier.Has(AccessModifierType.Public) && 
    modifier.Has(AccessModifierType.Static) &&
    modifier.Has(AccessModifierType.Privileged) && 
    modifier.Has(AccessModifierType.Private))
{
}
```

Comment: I used a version of that a few years ago but in .net 4.0 they incorporated the HasFlag() method for enums which I prefer.

Comment: @StrandedPirate: I didn't know that, very useful... switching to .NET 4.0 shortly :)